# Retrieving Dynamically Loaded Data From a Website

Tags: c#, javascript, html

I am attempting to retrieve data that is dynamically loaded onto a webpage using hashed links i.e. http://www.westfield.com.au/au/retailers#page=5

My question is what technology is being used to load the data onto the page?

Secondly, how would one approach retrieving this data using C#?

My attempts so far have used WebClient to download the page at this link, unfortunately the html file only contains the data from the very first page, no matter what page link i use.

Answer (score 1):

> What technology is being used to load the data onto the page?

JavaScript is used to load the data from a server, parse it into HTML and put it in the right place in the DOM.

> Secondly, how would one approach retrieving this data using C#?

Make a request to: `http://www.westfield.com.au/api/v1/countries/au/retail-chains/search.json?page=5`, it will return a structured JSON document containing the data you need.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is the JSON structure, Jon's answer sounds like a good place to start.

If you want a good stack for true rendered scraping I'd use a combination of [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/index.html) and [Selenium](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver) to help bridge it to .net.

[This](http://www.andykelk.net/tech/headless-browser-testing-with-phantomjs-selenium-webdriver-c-nunit-and-mono) article is a great place to start.